# Get command output from detached screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I am running a detached `screen` session, and running a command into it with `screen -X`, like so:

```
screen -S $SESSION -X <command>
```

This works fine, though I would like to be able to catch the output of the command without entering the screen. Is there some way to, from the command line, dump the history?

As a workaround, I tried to turn on the log for the session by doing

```
screen -L -S $SESSION -X <command>
```

but it does not seem to create a log file.

So, in summary, is it possible to dump the screen history for a running detached screen session *or* is it possible to turn on and off logging for a running detached session?

Comment: asked and answered http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12601/how-to-get-the-output-inside-screen-out-to-a-script or better yet http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110235/74222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a screen with logging enabled, use

```bsh
screen -L <command>
```

To enable logging on an existing screen

```bsh
screen -X log
```

you might want to specify which screen if you have multiple running using -S

The log will contain everything the screen sends to stdout from when logging was enabled.
You may want to remove screenlog.X and re-enable logging to get the most recent output.